# differntiate same values in array, js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

What i want to achieve is to make every element in array different and unique from others.

So if you imagine such a array:

```
let myArray = Array(10, 10, 10, 10, 9);
```

I want to put it through such algorithm:

1. Takie first element of an array (10) (index = 0).
2. check if there is element in array with the same value. yes there is - with index 1. if not, check next element...
3. change myArray[0] to myArray[0] + 1
4. change myArray[1] to myArray[1] - 1
5. return myArray

Now array looks like this:

```
myArray = Array(11, 9, 10, 10, 9)
```

Now it runs again, and next steps return such array:

```
myArray = Array(11, 10, 10, 10, 8) 
myArray = Array(11, 11, 9, 10, 8)
myArray = Array(12, 10, 9, 10, 8)
myArray = Array(12, 11, 9, 8, 8)
myArray = Array(12, 11, 10, 9, 7)
```

Now, because there are only unique values, it finishes.
It is easy to make it with while and for loops, but how can i do it with ES6 functional programming?

K.

Comment: The only functional part of your algorithm is "*check if there is element in array with the same value*". The rest is totally imperative, and can hardly expressed with functional programming methods.

Comment: and also, can you show your best try?

Comment: should the line with `11, 11, 9, 10, 9` be `11, 11, 9, 10, >8<`?

Comment: @NinaScholz jest it should - i edited and your example works perfecly fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a nested iteration with short circuit, if two same values are found.

```js
function fn(array) {
    return array.some((v, i, a) => a.slice(i + 1).some((w, j) => { 
        if (v === w) {
            ++a[i];
            --a[i + j + 1];
            return true;
        }
    }));
}
    
var array = [10, 10, 10, 10, 9];

console.log(array.join(' '));
while (fn(array)) console.log(array.join(' '));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A more functional style, which returns a new array

```js
const
    init = j => (v, i, a) => j !== -1
        ? i === j ? v - 1 : v
        : (j = a.indexOf(v, i + 1)) !== -1 ? v + 1 : v,
    upDown = () => init(-1);
    
var array = [10, 10, 10, 10, 9];

do {
    console.log(array.join(' '))
} while (array.join() !== (array = array.map(upDown())).join())
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'd rather go with `j = a.indexOf(v, i+1)` instead of an inner `some`. But those mutations inside the callback don't look very functional anyway.